# VBA/MS Access, clear select items on new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list box that I populate with a Table/Query and "select" multiple entries with a bit of VBA code. On Form_Current, I intend for the code to select whatever items in that listbox that are selected for the current record (saved in another table).

When I click to go to the next record, the previously selected list box items are still selected. How do I clear them? I would have thought a new record would do all of this for me automatically.

I'm just getting back into VBA for the first time in 12 years, so I'm no guru.

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: Editing records with a listbox is a rather odd way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([found here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-12.html)):

```
Function ClearList(lst As ListBox) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_ClearList
    'Purpose:   Unselect all items in the listbox.
    'Return:    True if successful
    'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com  June, 2006.
    Dim varItem As Variant

    If lst.MultiSelect = 0 Then
        lst = Null
    Else
        For Each varItem In lst.ItemsSelected
            lst.Selected(varItem) = False
        Next
    End If

    ClearList = True

Exit_ClearList:
    Exit Function

Err_ClearList:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "ClearList()")
    Resume Exit_ClearList
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - I saw that code somewhere but couldn't get it working. Now it is. I am doing `ListBoxPrograms = ClearList(ListBoxPrograms)` where before I tried `ListBoxPrograms.ClearList()` and `ClearList(ListBoxPrograms)` with no success. The first one works but why does VBA require a variable to receive the return? Should I set it to another variable or is what I have okay? Thanks for the help - Hans

Comment: You could equally do it as a Sub, and you wouldn't require the variable. But there is something to be said for checking return values, mind you.

Comment: You should do it either as `ClearList Me!ListBoxPrograms` or `Call ClearList(Me!ListBoxPrograms)` or `MyBooleanVariable = ClearList(Me!ListBoxPrograms)`. No other way will work. You you did `ListBoxPrograms = ClearList(ListBoxPrograms)`. That means you're clearing the selections but then setting the listbox value property to True. That's nonsense, and could cause problems (I'm surprised it doesn't cause an error, actually).